# Receiving mail in google app engine, handler works but a datastore entity is not created

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The datastore entity gets created in the dev server.

However, when I deploy the app and send a mail, it receives the mail and runs the handler however no datastore entities are created, here is the handler code:

```
  1 import logging, email
  2 import wsgiref.handlers
  3 from google.appengine.ext import webapp
  4 from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
  5 from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
  6 from google.appengine.ext import db
  7 from datetime import datetime
  8 from google.appengine.api import mail
  9 
 10 class mails(db.Model):
 11   fro = db.StringProperty()
 12   sub = db.StringProperty()
 13   time = db.DateTimeProperty()
 14   body = db.StringProperty()
 15   to = db.StringProperty()
 16   count = db.BooleanProperty(default=False) 
 17 
 18 class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
 19   def receive(self, mail_message):
 20     logging.info("mail received from "+mail_message.sender)
 21     if mail_message.sender.split('@')[1] in ('bits-goa.ac.in', 'bits-pilani.ac.in'):
 22       store = mails()
 23       store.fro = mail_message.sender
 24 
 25       try:
 26         store.sub = mail_message.subject
 27       except:
 28         pass
 29 
 30       try:
 31         store.time = datetime.strptime(mail_message.date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0630')
 32       except:
 33         pass
 34       body = ""
 35       for b in mail_message.bodies("text/plain"):
 36         body_type, pl = b
 37         try:
 38           if pl.encoding:
 39             body = pl.payload.decode(pl.payload.encoding)
 40           else:
 41             body = pl.payload
 42         except Exception, e:
 43           logging.debug("Body: %s" % (pl))
 44       store.body = body
 45       store.to = mail_message.to
 46       if not db.Query(mails).filter('fro =', mail_message.sender).get():
 47         store.count = True
 48         sender_add = "thanks@bitsconv.appspotmail.com"
 49         subject = "Thank you"
 50         mail_body = "Your vote will be counted"
 51         mail.send_mail(sender_add, mail_message.sender, subject, body)
 52       store.put()
 53     logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
 54 
 55 #application = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
 56 
 57 def main():
 58   logging.info("handled")
 59   application = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
 60   wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
 61 
 62 if __name__ == '__main__':
 63     main()
```

In my log, I see these 3 logs for each mail:

```
logging.info("handled")
logging.info("mail received from "+mail_message.sender)
logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
```

Comment: @jck what do you see in your log?

Comment: @systempuntoout: I edited the post to reflect this

Comment: I wouldn't let all the exceptions pass by...

Comment: Note that both of your log entries are created outside the block of code starting `if mail_message.sender.split` -- there's no way from those log entries to know if any of the code in that block is executed at all.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that before opening this page. I'm a dumbass. The problem is that mail_message.sender is something like Name <Address> and in the dev env it is the email address directly

Comment: @jck: you should never use `try: ... except: pass`. It will catch all exceptions, including syntax errors, and ignore them. Catch specific exceptions and handle them.

Comment: @jck What i mean is: you're not handling the exceptions, you're just catching them, but letting them go away unhandled. That way you'll never see what's wrong in your code, exactly what Wooble said.

Comment: @Wooble It won't catch syntax errors, but it will catch exceptions due to missing identifiers.

Comment: `body = pl.payload.decode(pl.payload.encoding)` - is it correct code? Shouldn't it `be body = pl.payload.decode(pl.encoding)`? With your version I am getting error `'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'`.